# How to reload component in angular4

Tags: angular

I have worked on angular 4 applications. My requirement is:- 
I have a search button on header component and if I search anything, go to search component and display the result. But when I search again in the  header, it does not reload the search component.

Please tell us how to reload the component on click search button.

Comment: Please paste your code so people can help by looking at what you have written. Also, you don't reload components; you change the objects the components use to create views. Components are simply created and destroyed depending on how you handle them.

Comment: If query parameters on routes is change again and again, so to get the result on search component if does not refresh the page. I have get the query params in component constructor

Comment: If you change the query parameters, the page will not refresh; this is because the base url is the same and the component that handles the view is the same, so Angular does not destroy the component. What you want to do is to save your query result as a local variable in your component, and use that variable to generate your view. Whenever you search with new result, you will refresh the variable so the page reflects the changes.

Comment: How is your code structure? You want to reload search component or there is another Results component?

Answer (score 2):

You will be writing something along the lines of these. Please paste your own code next time so it would be easier for people to help.

#### my.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { SearchService } from '[your own search service]';
export class MyComponent {
    items : { id: number, name: string}[];
    searchForm : FormGroup;

    constructor( 
        private searchService : SearchService,
        private formBuilder : FormBuilder ) {
        this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
            searchField : ""
        } );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.search();
    }

    search() {
        let searchValue = this.searchForm.get( "searchField" ).value();
        // Your search service should return an Observable
        this.searchService.search( searchValue ).subscribe(
            data => {
                // Refreshes search result
                this.items = data.json();
            },
            error => {
                // Error handling
            }
        );
    }
}
```

#### my.component.html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
......
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Field" formControlName="searchField" />
    <button (click)="search()">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reload the  `search component` whenever you click search button in your header component or clicking enter.

```
  // whenever enter is hit anywhere in this component, search() will be called
  @HostListener('keyup.enter', ['searchInput']) search(searchInput: string) {
    // check for minimum chanractor
    if (searchText.length > this.MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH) {
      this.error = false;
      // now navigate to the search component
      this.router.navigate(['search', searchInput], {
        queryParams: {
          match: this.match.join(',')
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.error = true;
    }
  }
```

In the above code on every time search navigating to the search component so it will create a new instance.